# Prove the languages |L<M>| = 2 and |L<M>| $\not=$ 2 to be non-Turing recognizable or non-recursively enumerable

Tags: turing-machines, computability, reductions, semi-decidability

I am trying to prove the **non**-recursively enumerable property of two languages.

$L_2 = \{\langle M \rangle: |L\langle M \rangle| = 2\}$ and
$L_{\not=2} = \{\langle M \rangle: |L\langle M \rangle| \not= 2\}$.

**My idea** is to use the following two properties:

1. If A $\leq_m$ B and A is not Turing recognizable then B is not Turing-recognizable.
2. A $\leq_m$ B if and only if $A^c \leq_m B^c$.

For language $L_{2}$, 
If I can show that $A_{TM}$ is mapping reducible to $L_{\not=2}$, according to **property 2** we could get that $\overline{A_{TM}}$(the complement of $A_{TM}$) is mapping reducible to $L_{2}$, and for the fact that $\overline{A_{TM}}$ is not Turing recognizable, we could get that $L_{=2}$ is not Turing recognizable.

For language $L_{\not=2}$, 
If I can show that $\overline{A_{TM}}$ is also mapping reducible to $L_{\not=2}$, and for the fact that $\overline{A_{TM}}$ is not Turing recognizable, we could get that $L_{\not=2}$ is not Turing recognizable.

However, I don't know how to prove the mapping reducible relationships between them. Or my direction could be totally wrong.

Could somebody give me the hints or possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I can show that $A_{TM}$ is mapping reducible to $L_{=2}$, ...

That is a nice idea. Given $\langle M, w \rangle$, can you construct a TM $M_1$ that accepts only one word, the word $w$ if and only if $M$ accepts $w$?

Then, can you change $M_1$ so that it accepts another word that is different from $w$?

You can also show that $A_{TM}$ is mapping reducible to $L_{\not=2}$ by creating a TM $M_3$ which accepts 2 words if $M$ does not accepts $w$ and 3 words otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your replying! However, I am little confused about the concept of mapping reduction from $A_{TM}$.  If I could construct a Turing machine, let's call it M and M could accept some input, then is it trivial to say that it is mapping reducible from $A_{TM}$ for the fact that $A_{TM}$ contains all encodings of all Turing machines that accept some input?

Comment: Please come to [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90539/accepting-two-words-non-recursively-enumerable)

Comment: My reputation is not enough to talk in the chatroom. Thanks again for your explanation!

Comment: From $\langle M,w \rangle\in A_{TM}$, you can construct a new TM $M_w$, which accepts word $w$ and no other words. That would be a reduction from $A_{TM}$ to $\{\langle M \rangle: |L\langle M \rangle| = 1\}$. Adjust that construction a bit, you can create a reduction $A_{TM}$ to $L_2$.